# Python: How to compare txt files

Tags: compare, diff

There are two files a.txt and b.txt. The string in a.txt will be part of the string in b.txt, but not 100% the same

Under a.txt:

192.168.1.1

192.168.1.4

Under b.txt:

./192.168.1.1_Hello

./192.168.1.4_World

./tmp.txt

My final goal is to check the list in b.txt covers all IP in a.txt. If it is not correct, I want the program output those IP to me. Do you guys have any ideas on this ? it seems “diff” command on Python is not a good idea.